# Make `_doPostBack` requests using postman

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, postman

I am scraping some data from https://www.iob.in/bc_locator.aspx and the page loads the data for the next contents of the table through a request like `__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv_Branch','Page$n')` where `n` is page number.

I am able to make normal request through URL but can't find a way to mimic `__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv_Branch','Page$n'` through postman. Any ideas for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page is a webform developed with Asp.Net. The first time you visit the web site, you get a cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId` that identifies your machine. You need to attach this cookie to the postback, otherwise it would fail.

To achieve that programatically, just make simple `GET` to `https://www.iob.in` and retrieve the cookie. Then send a `POST` to `https://www.iob.in/bc_locator.aspx` with the cookie attached.

**Postman:**

```json
{
    "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv_Branch",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "Page$1"
}
```

In order to navigate to other pages by running Asp events you might need `__VIEWSTATE`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`. `__EVENTVALIDATION`, etc. Get them from the original page.